# Invoke function once runserver command was called

Tags: python, django, matlab

I have a django application that has its own models and views. When I start django server with `python manage.py runserver` I want to open a matlab instance, preload environment there, and send this instance to each request made. How can I do this?
You can assume I have a matlab wrapper for python:

```
class MatlabWrapper(object):
    def __init__(self):
        ...

    def run(self):
        ...

    def execute(self, cmd):
        ...

    def exit(self):
        ...

# usage
m = MatlabWrapper()
m.run() # launch matlab
m.execute(cmd1) # execute command 1
m.execute(cmd2) # execute command 2
```